# getting context path with URL tag

Tags: struts2, contextpath

I am having application deployed in the URL
    HOST_NAME/abc/appname/login.action

and when using Struts 2 URL tag

```
<s:url id="testURL" action="login">
</s:url>
```

am getting
    HOST_NAME/appname/login.action 
instead of 
    HOST_NAME/abc/appname/login.action
How to get the *abc* in path in the URL without hardcoding it?

Comment: Have you checked your struts xml? which is the namespace defined there for the action you are calling?

Comment: i have used namespace="/"

Answer (score 0):

**Hi Hariharan**

Change the namespace defined in your **`struts.xml`** file.
Instead of **`namespace="/"`** use **`namespace="/abc"`**.

This will redirect your actions to the desired path and I hope this will help you.

Comment: `HOST_NAME/abc/appname` isn't the same as `HOST_NAME/appname/abc`.